# Problem with a simple code using the Math class

Tags: java, class, math, types, return

So i have tried every thing but for some reason my programm in JAVA cannot compile at all. I think there's something wrong with the types of data at Math methods i am using. Here's the code

```
public static int getOuthaul(int manganous, int nakir) {
    if (manganous > nakir) {
        double tmp = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(manganous - nakir));
        return Math.round(tmp);
    }
}
```

I DESPERATELY NEED AN ANSWER GUYS. IT WOULD MEAN A LOT!!
Thanks

This is the whole class:

```
public class Vijao {
    public static int getOuthaul(int manganous, int nakir) {
        if (manganous > nakir) {
            double tmp = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(manganous - nakir));
            float mpp = (float)tmp;
            return Math.round(tmp);
        } else {
            return Math.abs(manganous - nakir);
        }
    }

    public static int getUnhulled(int toilfully, int corse, int outwrench) {
        int wilbur = corse + 16 * toilfully;
        if (wilbur * wilbur > outwrench)
            return wilbur;
        else {
            return wilbur * (-1);
        
    }
}
```

And that's th mistake

error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int
return Math.round(tmp);
^

Comment: Post all the class code

Comment: When this is the whole method you need a closing bracket and a return after the if .... what should the method return when the if is not executed

Comment: Please post the exact compilation errors you're seeing.

Comment: Care to share with us what error(s) you are getting. First issue is you are returning the result of `Math.round` which is probably a `double` but your method expects you to return an `int`

Comment: Please do not SHOUT at us!

Comment: Compiler errors are there to help you find the problem. Please copy them and paste them into the question.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace "}" at the end of your code sample. Could that be it?

Comment: "possible lossy conversion from long to int return Math.round(tmp);" --> Cast the the return value from `Math.round()` to int with: `return (int)Math.round(tmp);`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is a result of changing a variable from a higher(wider) type to a narrower one. For example, `float` is a 32-bit floating point data type while `int` is a 32-bit integral type. This results in **possibly** losing a value or a precision of a variable.

For instance, let's try to convert `float` to `int`:

```
float fl = 1.10f;
int in = fl; // throws incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from float to int
```

This could be solved by **downcasting**. Casting a large size type to a smaller-size type.

It goes this way:

```
float fl = 1.10f;
int in = (int) fl; // prints 1
```

In your case, the method `getOuthaul()` has a return type of `int`, but is returning `double`(which is wider than an `int`).

Though `Math.abs()` could return `int`, `Math.sqrt()` returns `double`. So, it would be wise to select which type is adequate for your needs and handle accordingly. Here I will change them to `long`, the return type of `Math.round()`.

```
public static long getOuthaul(int manganous, int nakir) {
    if (manganous > nakir) {
        double tmp = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(manganous - nakir));
        return Math.round(tmp);
    } else {
        return Math.abs(manganous - nakir);
    }
}
```

== **UPDATE** ==

In case the return type must be an `int`:

```
public static int getOuthaul(int manganous, int nakir) {
    if (manganous > nakir) {
        double tmp = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(manganous - nakir));
        return Math.round((float)tmp); //not the cast to float
    } else {
        return Math.abs(manganous - nakir);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the function, `getOuthaul` is `int` but you are trying to return  `Math.round(tmp)` [which returns a long value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)). The size of an `int` variable is `4` bytes whereas a `long` value needs `8` bytes of size to be held into.

Now that you understand the problem, you can apply one of the following solutions as per your requirement:

1. Change the return type of the function, `getOuthaul` to `long`
2. Cast the value of `Math.round(tmp)` to `int` i.e. `return (int) Math.round(tmp);`